# Copying android studio setup from one system to another without downloading any files

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, copy, settings

Is it necessary to download android sdk for each and every system we install android studiod? Isnt there a way to copy the whole setup from one computer to another ?

Comment: based on os you use , if the same os is used in the system you going to copy it wont be any problem just copy whole sdk and give path it will work

Comment: Technically you could copy all of it, there shouldn't be any problems. It depends on your OS where you can find the folders you need to copy. But in any case: I wouldn't recommend copying it. Why is it a problem to download the sdk on each computer? You just need the build tools and platform tools, as well as the support library etc. It's not that much. Android Studio mostly takes care of downloading those dependencies once you need them.

Comment: downloading takes a lot of time. we are trying to set in up in 10 systems so instead of downloading in every system , cant we copy and refer in other systems ?

Comment: As I said: yes you can copy the sdk, but why does it take so long to download it? The parts that are really necessary for Android development are just a few MB. You don't need the whole thing. And if you ever need something you don't have installed then Android Studio will download it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the whole Android Studio Folder (don't has to be installed on C) should work.
*Not tested!*

Answer (score 0):

Android website have options to download only the sdks whichever you want.

And then when you install Android Studio afterwards, when it first opens it will ask you to point out the path for Android SDK either on the first windows that pops up or in the settings tab.

So just copy the SDKs into the system everytime you have to install Android Studio and just simply point it out from it.